# PHP display data based on day for current week alone

Tags: php

i have tried to display online classes based on days, within current week, So all i need is to display Monday: 3 classes, Tuesday: 2 classes, Friday: 4 classes, Saturday: 3 classes, thats all, but in my code whatever class is more than one class its repeating and jumping to another Day. just check the expected output image dates you may get a clear idea

**Expected Output**

[image: image1]

This is what coming right now,
**Error Image**

[image: error image]

Below is my code please check the code part and give me the logic to display

```html
<div class="row">
                            <?php
if ($total_arr)
{
    $mon = true;
    $tue = true;
    $wed = true;
    $thu = true;
    $fri = true;
    $sat = true;
    foreach ($total_arr as $bb_ky => $bb_v)
    {
        $dayName = date('l', strtotime($bb_v->openingtimed));
        $setStartD = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($bb_v->openingtimed));
        $setStartT = date('h.i a', $bb_v->openingtime);
        $setEndT = date('h.i a', $bb_v->closingtime);
        $chkStart = date('Y-m-d H:i', $bb_v->openingtime);
        $chkEnd = date('Y-m-d H:i', $bb_v->closingtime);
?> 
                                
                                <?php if ($dayName == "Monday")
        { ?>
                                    <?php if ($mon)
            { ?>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">                                         
                                            <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo $dayName . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php
            }
            $mon = false; ?>
                                    
                                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3" >
                                        <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                                          <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                          <div class="class-status">
                                            <?php echo $status; ?>
                                          </div>
                                            <div class="live-btn">
                                                <?php echo $livebtn; ?>
                                            </div> 
                                            
                                            <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $bb_v->name ?></p>                                
                                            <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                                            <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small> 
                                            <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                  
                                          </div>                              
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php
        } ?>
                                    
                                <?php if ($dayName == "Tuesday")
        { ?>
                                    <?php if ($tue)
            { ?>
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
                                                <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo $dayName . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
                                            </div>
                                    <?php
            }
            $tue = false; ?>
                                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3" >
                                        <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                                          <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                          <div class="class-status">
                                            <?php echo $status; ?>
                                          </div>
                                            <div class="live-btn">
                                                <?php echo $livebtn; ?>
                                            </div> 
                                            
                                            <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $bb_v->name ?></p>                                
                                            <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                                            <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small>  
                                            <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                 
                                          </div>                              
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php
        } ?>

                                <?php if ($dayName == "Wednesday")
        { ?>
                                    <?php if ($wed)
            { ?>
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
                                                <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo $dayName . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
                                            </div>
                                    <?php
            }
            $wed = false; ?>
                                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3" >
                                        <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                                          <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                          <div class="class-status">
                                            <?php echo $status; ?>
                                          </div>
                                            <div class="live-btn">
                                                <?php echo $livebtn; ?>
                                            </div> 
                                            
                                            <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $bb_v->name ?></p>                                
                                            <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                                            <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small> 
                                            <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                  
                                          </div>                              
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                <?php
        } ?>

                                <?php if ($dayName == "Thursday")
        { ?>
                                    <?php if ($thu)
            { ?>
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mt-4" >
                                                <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo $dayName . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
                                            </div>
                                    <?php
            }
            $thu = false; ?>
                                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3" >
                                        <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                                          <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                          <div class="class-status">
                                            <?php echo $status; ?>
                                          </div>
                                            <div class="live-btn">
                                                <?php echo $livebtn; ?>
                                            </div> 
                                            
                                            <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $bb_v->name ?></p>                                
                                            <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                                            <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small>   
                                            <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                
                                          </div>                              
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                <?php
        } ?>

                                <?php if ($dayName == "Friday")
        { ?>
                                    <?php if ($fri)
            { ?>
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
                                                <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo $dayName . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
                                            </div>
                                    <?php
            }
            $fri = false; ?>
                                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">
                                        <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                                          <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                          <div class="class-status">
                                            <?php echo $status; ?>
                                          </div>
                                            <div class="live-btn">
                                                <?php echo $livebtn; ?>
                                            </div> 
                                            
                                            <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $bb_v->name ?></p>                                
                                            <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                                            <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small>  
                                            <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                 
                                          </div>                              
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                <?php
        } ?>

                                <?php if ($dayName == "Saturday")
        { ?>
                                    <?php if ($sat)
            { ?>
                                            <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
                                                <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo $dayName . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
                                            </div>
                                    <?php
            }
            $sat = false; ?>
                                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">
                                        <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                                          <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                          <div class="class-status">
                                            <?php echo $status; ?>
                                          </div>
                                            <div class="live-btn">
                                                <?php echo $livebtn; ?>
                                            </div> 
                                            
                                            <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $bb_v->name ?></p>                                
                                            <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                                            <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small>  
                                            <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                 
                                          </div>                              
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                <?php
        } ?>
                            <?php
    }
} ?>
                        </div>
```

Waiting for your answers, Thank you

Comment: So what's the issue with your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @Meta Pakistani  It is not coming as expected, just check the screenshot i have attached you might have a clear view

Comment: please be specific while asking question, it's hard to read these much lines

Comment: s i have tried to display online classes based on days, within current week, So all i need is to display Monday, 3 classes, Tuesday 2 classes, Friday, 4 classes, Saturday 3 classes, thats all, but in my code whatever class is more than one class its repeating  and jumping to another class. just check the expected output image dates you may get a clear idea

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is run the loop first to create a new array & sort your classes into seperate "day" based groups, then loop through that list & generate your output.

### Loop 1:

same as before, but switch through the day value, assign all classes to that day.

### Loop 2:

loop through each index(1,2,3,4,5,6)

then loop through each day("Monday"),

then inner loop, through each class(array) for that day,

this should allow you to only write 1 section of html...

hopefully this helps in someway..

ie:

```
if ($total_arr)
{
    $classes = array();
    foreach ($total_arr as $bb_ky => $bb_v)
    {
        $dayToCheck = date('l', strtotime($bb_v->openingtimed));
        switch($dayToCheck)
        {
           case "Monday" :
               $classes[1]['monday'][] = $bb_v;
           break;
           case "Tuesday" :
               $classes[2]['tuesday'][] = $bb_v;
           break;
           case "Wednesday" :
               $classes[3]['wednesday'][] = $bb_v;
           break;
           case "Thursday" :
               $classes[4]['thursday'][] = $bb_v;
           break;
           case "Friday" :
               $classes[5]['friday'][] = $bb_v;
           break;
           case "Saturday" :
               $classes[6]['saturday'][] = $bb_v;
           break;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($classes))
    {
       foreach($classes as $weekDay)
       {
         foreach($weekDay as $theDayName=>$class)
         {
           echo "<h2>".ucfirst($theDayName)."</h2>";
           foreach($class as $row)
           {
              $dayName   = date('l', strtotime($row->openingtimed));
              $setStartD = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($row->openingtimed));
              $setStartT = date('h.i a', $row->openingtime);
              $setEndT   = date('h.i a', $row->closingtime);
              $chkStart  = date('Y-m-d H:i', $row->openingtime);
              $chkEnd    = date('Y-m-d H:i', $row->closingtime);

              ?>
              <div class="col-md-12">                                         
                 <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo $dayName . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3" >
                 <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                    <div class="card-body pb-0">
                       <div class="class-status"><?php echo $status; ?></div>
                       <div class="live-btn"><?php echo $livebtn; ?></div> 
                       <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $row->name ?></p>                                
                       <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                       <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small> 
                       <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                  
                    </div>                              
                 </div>
             </div>
           <?php
          }
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: No brother its not coming correctly..., check the Output URL https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IgkH_WkEnIcCrAzShUDaT62oABAFso2G/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The 2nd loop where its setting values should be using `$row` not `$bb_v`

Comment: but here you have added $row as just a variable in loop please check code

Comment: sorry guys, yea, I forgot to reuse the $row var within the inner loop.. updated code example..

Comment: thanks brother its coming correctly but order of the week is not coming correctly like before..Monday,Tuesday it must come like that, currently it shows Friday First

Comment: sorry man.. need to think of a way to sort your array, obviously cant use asort, ksort... may have to add an index instead of the actual name, ie: array( 1 => "Monday", array(classes), 2 => "Tuesday", array(classes) ... )

Comment: @Marty Brother could you make it please, trying this from morning !

Comment: updated above example. included another "OUTER" foreach loop, this should loop around the index based array ie: 1,2,3,4,5,6..... then another foreach loop to loop each weekDay & course... then Another loop to loop around each class....? :)

Comment: worked on my test case, but I dont have all your data...just try looping around each array & use print_r() on the $weekDay, $class & $row

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you i tried and got the answer...Find the below code

```html
<div class="row">
<?php
    if ($total_arr){
        $mon = true;$tue = true;$wed = true;thu = true;$fri = true;$sat = true;
        $days = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        foreach ($days as $dkey => $dvalue){
            foreach ($total_arr as $bb_ky => $bb_v){
                $dayName = $bb_v->openingtimedd;
                $setStartD = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($bb_v->openingtimed));
                $setStartT = date('h.i a', $bb_v->openingtime);
                $setEndT = date('h.i a', $bb_v->closingtime);
                $chkStart = date('Y-m-d H:i', $bb_v->openingtime);
                $chkEnd = date('Y-m-d H:i', $bb_v->closingtime);
                if ($chkStart <= date("Y-m-d H:i") && $chkEnd >= date("Y-m-d H:i")){
                    $status = '<a class="text-success">On Going</a>';
                    $livebtn = '<a class="btn btn-success text-white get_bbtn" data-metid="' . $bb_v->meetingid . '" data-cid="' . @$get_cmid->id . '" data-id="' . $bb_v->id . '">
                    Live <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
                    </a>';
                } else if ($chkStart < date("Y-m-d H:i")) {
                    $status = '<a class="text-secondary">Completed</a>';
                    $livebtn = '<a class="btn btn-secondary text-white get_bbtn" data-metid="" data-cid="" data-id="">
                    Live <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
                    </a>';
                } else if ($chkStart > date("Y-m-d H:i")){
                    $status = '<a class="text-info">Upcoming</a>';
                    $livebtn = '<a class="btn btn-info text-white get_bbtn" data-metid="" data-cid="" data-id="">
                    Live <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
                    </a>';
                }
                ?> 

                <?php 
                    if ($bb_v->openingtimedd == $dvalue && $dvalue == 0){
                        if ($mon){ ?>
                        <div class="col-md-12">                                         
                        <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo date('l', $bb_v->openingtime) . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                $mon = false; 
                ?>

                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3" >
                    <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                    <div class="card-body pb-0">
                    <div class="class-status">
                    <?php echo $status; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="live-btn">
                    <?php echo $livebtn; ?>
                    </div> 

                    <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $bb_v->name ?></p>                                
                    <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                    <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small> 
                    <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                  
                    </div>                            
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php 
                    if ($bb_v->openingtimedd == $dvalue && $dvalue == 1){
                        if ($tue){ ?>
                        <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
                        <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo date('l', $bb_v->openingtime) . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                $tue = false; 
                ?>
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3" >
                    <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                    <div class="card-body pb-0">
                    <div class="class-status">
                    <?php echo $status; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="live-btn">
                    <?php echo $livebtn; ?>
                    </div> 

                    <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $bb_v->name ?></p>                                
                    <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                    <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small>  
                    <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                 
                    </div>                            
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if ($bb_v->openingtimedd == $dvalue && $dvalue == 2){
                    if ($wed)
                    { ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
                    <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo date('l', $bb_v->openingtime) . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    $wed = false; ?>
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3" >
                    <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                    <div class="card-body pb-0">
                    <div class="class-status">
                    <?php echo $status; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="live-btn">
                    <?php echo $livebtn; ?>
                    </div> 

                    <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $bb_v->name ?></p>                                
                    <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                    <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small> 
                    <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                  
                    </div>                            
                    </div>
                    </div>

                <?php
                } ?>

                <?php if ($bb_v->openingtimedd == $dvalue && $dvalue == 3)
                {
                    if ($thu)
                    { ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-4" >
                    <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo date('l', $bb_v->openingtime) . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    $thu = false; ?>
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3" >
                    <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                    <div class="card-body pb-0">
                    <div class="class-status">
                    <?php echo $status; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="live-btn">
                    <?php echo $livebtn; ?>
                    </div> 

                    <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $bb_v->name ?></p>                                
                    <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                    <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small>   
                    <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                
                    </div>                            
                    </div>
                    </div>

                <?php
                } ?>

                <?php if ($bb_v->openingtimedd == $dvalue && $dvalue == 4)
                    {
                    if ($fri)
                    { ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
                    <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo date('l', $bb_v->openingtime) . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    $fri = false; ?>
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">
                    <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                    <div class="card-body pb-0">
                    <div class="class-status">
                    <?php echo $status; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="live-btn">
                    <?php echo $livebtn; ?>
                    </div> 

                    <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $bb_v->name ?></p>                                
                    <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                    <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small>  
                    <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                 
                    </div>                            
                    </div>
                    </div>

                <?php
                } ?>

                <?php if ($bb_v->openingtimedd == $dvalue && $dvalue == 5)
                    {
                    if ($sat)
                    { ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
                    <h5 class="subtitle"><?php echo date('l', $bb_v->openingtime) . ' ' . $setStartD; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    $sat = false; ?>
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">
                    <div class="card dark-white bg-default o-hidden h-100 mt-3">              
                    <div class="card-body pb-0">
                    <div class="class-status">
                    <?php echo $status; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="live-btn">
                    <?php echo $livebtn; ?>
                    </div> 

                    <p class="live-class-left"><?php echo $bb_v->name ?></p>                                
                    <small><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $setStartD; ?></small><br>
                    <small><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo $setStartT; ?> to <?php echo $setEndT; ?></small>  
                    <img class="mr-1 float-right" src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/iomadboost/images/mod_images/live-icon.png">                 
                    </div>                            
                    </div>
                    </div>

                <?php
                } ?>
                <?php
            }
    }
} ?>
</div>
```

I think this is another way...which worked for me, Thanks